# Awk script to extract the Multiple different delimiter lines

Tags: awk

Log file:

```
25 Apr 2022 02:55:08,062  ; 12345678908,123456789, added soc:[DSPSIA2D9,450, USGPRSPPF,0] deleted soc:[] ldap soc:[DSPSIA2D9,450, OPTSRA1H7,52, USGPRSPPF,0] db SOC:[OPTSRA1H7,52]

25 Apr 2022 02:55:08,872  ; 98765432101,234567833, added soc:[DSPSIA2EB,450, USGPRSPPF,0] deleted soc:[DSPSIA2CZ,450] ldap soc:[BBSUSPEND,0, DSPSIA2EB,450, OPTSRA1H7,52, USGPRSPPF,0, BBSUSPEND,0, USGPRSPPF,0] db SOC:[BBSUSPEND,0, BBSUSPEND,0, DSPSIA2CZ,450, OPTSRA1H7,52, USGPRSPPF,0]

25 Apr 2022 02:55:09,413  ; 23456789022,123456789, added soc:[DSPSIA2D6,450] deleted soc:[DSPSIA0R6,450] ldap soc:[BBSUSPEND,0, DSPSIA2D6,450, OPTSRA1H7,52, USGPRSPPF,0, BBSUSPEND,0] db SOC:[BBSUSPEND,0, BBSUSPEND,0, DSPSIA0R6,450, OPTSRA1H7,52, USGPRSPPF,0]
```

If the "added soc" contains "USGPRSPPF" and extract the sixth column values.

Output:

```
12345678908
98765432101
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered to see how to format your input, output, and code as "Code Blocks" and then [edit] your question to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
25 Apr 2022 02:55:08,062 ; 12345678908,123456789, added soc:[DSPSIA2D9,450, USGPRSPPF,0] deleted soc:[] ldap soc:[DSPSIA2D9,450, OPTSRA1H7,52, USGPRSPPF,0] db SOC:[OPTSRA1H7,52]

25 Apr 2022 02:55:08,872 ; 98765432101,234567833, added soc:[DSPSIA2EB,450, USGPRSPPF,0] deleted soc:[DSPSIA2CZ,450] ldap soc:[BBSUSPEND,0, DSPSIA2EB,450, OPTSRA1H7,52, USGPRSPPF,0, BBSUSPEND,0, USGPRSPPF,0] db SOC:[BBSUSPEND,0, BBSUSPEND,0, DSPSIA2CZ,450, OPTSRA1H7,52, USGPRSPPF,0]

25 Apr 2022 02:55:09,413 ; 23456789022,123456789, added soc:[DSPSIA2D6,450] deleted soc:[DSPSIA0R6,450] ldap soc:[BBSUSPEND,0, DSPSIA2D6,450, OPTSRA1H7,52, USGPRSPPF,0, BBSUSPEND,0] db SOC:[BBSUSPEND,0, BBSUSPEND,0, DSPSIA0R6,450, OPTSRA1H7,52, USGPRSPPF,0]
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[[:space:]]+|,"}/added soc:\[[^\]]*USGPRSPPF/{print $7}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
12345678908
98765432101
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator (`FS`) is one or more (`+`) whitespace characters or (`|`) `,`. Then for every line which contain `added soc:[` followed by zero or more not-`]` followed by `USGPRSPPF` I `print` 7th field. Note that literal `[` and `]` needs to be escaped as they have special meaning inside regular expression.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*